# Is $SO(n)$ a normal subgroup of $SO(n+1)$?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to learn about homogeneous and symmetric spaces. I know that the quotient $SO(n+1)/SO(n)$ should look like the sphere $S^n$.

But how so (i.e, what is the equivalence criterion)? Is $SO(n)$ a normal subgroup and the quotient has a group isomorphism with $S^n$, or we simply have a diffeomorphism between the coset space $SO(n+1)/SO(n)$ and the sphere $S^n$?

Also, it would be really helpful if somebody can please suggest some survey/introductory literature on homogeneous spaces. Thank you very much for your help, comments are welcome!

Comment: This is a similar problem like [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30720/is-un-a-normal-subgroup-of-so2n). The quotients are not meant by normal subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $S^n$ is not a group for $n\neq 1,3$ (with those cases being the unit complex numbers and the unit quaternions under multiplication) $SO(n)$ is not a normal subgroup of $SO(n+1)$ in general. The group $SO(n)$ is a smooth subspace of the space $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ of $n$ by $n$ real matrices, and so if we put Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ then $SO(n)$ inherits the subspace topology. The claim is then that the space of right (say) cosets $SO(n+1)/SO(n)$ with the quotient topology is homeomorphic to $S^n$. One can further put differentiable structures on these spaces (as $SO(n)$ is a Lie group) and upgrade the homeomorphism to a diffeomorphism.

You can see the result from the orbit-stabiliser theorem. $SO(n+1)$ acts on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ by matrix multiplication. Consider the point $(1,0,\dots,0)$. Its orbit is $S^n$, while its stabiliser is the subgroup $SO(n)$ and so the result follows.

More generally for a Lie group $G$ with $H$ some Lie subgroup the space of right cosets $G/H$ is a homogeneous space. The space of cosets is a group iff $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please give me some references in general, for understanding and knowing the results on homogeneous spaces?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know any good textbooks on this subject. There do seem to be a lot of good lecture notes online if you google "homogeneous spaces lecture notes". This one even has some citations http://myweb.rz.uni-augsburg.de/~eschenbu/symspace.pdf

Comment: @CahalStrups  I have a student who wrote up a very nice set of notes on the coset space $SO(n)/SO(n-1)$.  It is at a basic level because he was an undergrad.  I find it to be very clear and readable.  I would be willing to share privately if you wanted.

Comment: @Randall That would be great, thank you so much !

Comment: @CahalStrups Sorry, kind of forgot.  Section 2 is what you want:  https://filehost.net/08aff050f6de311e

Comment: @AlecB-G, great answer! Just to make one thing explicit for the special case of $SO(4)$, the subgroup $SO(3)$ is normal. This is because $SO(4)/SO(3)=S^3$, which is a group, and this implies (by your last statement) that $SO(3)$ is normal. So $SO(4)$ is exceptional in having a normal Lie subgroup (ignoring discrete normal subgroups).