# What are the normal Lie subgroups of $SO(4)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, normal-subgroups

I'm interested in the *non-discrete* Lie subgroups.
(I've searched long for a resource that lists things like all normal subgroups for group a $G$, but have not found one.)

**Background**

My understanding (with $\triangleleft$ meaning normal subgroup):

$SU(2)\triangleleft SO(4)$ because isoclinic rotations in $SO(4)$ are normal ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space#Group_structure_of_SO(4))) and isomorphic to $SU(2)$ (answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671783/isoclinic-rotations-in-mathbbr4-are-what-subgroup-of-so4/4671809#4671809))

$SO(3)\triangleleft SO(4)$ because $SO(4)/SO(3)=S^3\cong SU(2)$, and because $SU(2)$ is a Lie group, and in $G/N=H$, $N$ is normal iff $H$ is a Lie group (rather than a non-group homogenous space) according to the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733750/is-son-a-normal-subgroup-of-son1). (EDIT: per Jason DeVito's comment below, my reasoning here was wrong: the quotient is $S^3$ without the structure of $SU(2)$.)

**Question:** are there other non-discrete $N\triangleleft SO(4)$?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Sorry, @Shaun. Done. Could you remove the downvote?

Comment: Thank you. It's now an upvote.

Comment: I don't have time to write a detailed polished answer, but the complete result is that there are precisely $5$ normal subgroups of $SO(4)$:  $\{I\}, \{\pm I\}, SU(2)_1, SU(2)_2, SO(4)$, where $I$ denotes the identity and $SU(2)_1$ and $SU(2)_2$ denote two distinct non-conjugate normal subgroups which are each isomorphic to $SU(2)$.  In particular, $SO(3)$ is *not* normal.  The issue with the linked answer is that $SO(4)/SO(3)$ is diffeomorphic to $SU(2)$, so happens to support a Lie group structure, but this structure is not induced from the group operation on $SO(4)$.

Comment: One way to see it:  first, convince yourself there is a surjective homomorphism $SU(2)\times SU(2)\rightarrow SO(4)$ with kernel $\{\pm(I,I)\}$.  Then convince yourself that the only normal subgroups of $SU(2)$ are $\{I\}, \{\pm I\}, SU(2)$, and then piece the answer together using several relatively straightforward group theory facts.

Comment: Thanks, @JasonDeVito. That was the information I needed. Just curious: is this something you just see from having much experience with SO(4) or SO(n)? Or is there a textbook or other resource to look up this (for the future)?

Comment: For me, whenever I see $SO(n)$ for $n\leq 6$, I generally replace it with its universal cover and try to answer questions tehre.  For larger $n$, I don't have a good picture of $Spin(n)$, so prefer to work with $SO(n)$.  I don't know of any text book or paper which deals with sufficiently terrible subgroups of a Lie groups.